# How to do Performance Testing of Android SDK using JMeter and Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: mobile, jmeter, android-emulator, performance-testing

I want to do client-side performance testing for android SDK using Android Studio and Jmeter.

I have tried with Jmeter script recorder for Android Emulator. Is it success way? and what is the best way to do that without using external mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can conduct performance testing of an "Android SDK" using JMeter.

If you want to assess [code complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), algorithms efficiency, resources usage like CPU, RAM, battery, etc. - you should rather go for [Android Studio Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile)

JMeter can help you to simulate hundreds/thousands of concurrent users using your application at the same time, to wit you don't test the "Android SDK", you test the **[backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend)** to which "Android SDK" talks to. In this case you don't need any mobile device or emulator as long as JMeter produces the same network footprint as your "Android SDK".

More information: [Challenges to Mobile App Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mobile-app-performance-testing)